# What is the limitation of Mass Emails for Developer edition

Tags: massemailmessage, mass-email

Hui Guys, could u help me to know limitations of Mass email for developer edition

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation says:

> In **Developer Edition** organizations and organizations evaluating
>   Salesforce during a trial period, **your organization can send mass
>   email to no more than 10 external email addresses per day.** This lower
>   limit does not apply if your organization was created before the
>   Winter '12 release and already had mass email enabled with a higher
>   limit. Additionally, your organization can send single emails to a
>   maximum of 15 email addresses per day.

More Info: [Mass Email Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_mass.htm)